# Is there a mapping of FHIR Systems to OMOP Vocabularies?

Tags: hl7-fhir, ohdsi-omop

Is there a mapping of FHIR systems to OMOP vocabularies?

The FHIR messages I’m working with are using things like this:

SNOMED            http://snomed.info/sct

RxNorm            http://www.nlm.nih.gov/research/umls/rxnorm

…and OMOP uses things like this:
[image]

So, I need something that will tell me when I see “http://snomed.info/sct” in my FHIR message I should be looking for the OMOP vocabulary with the vocabulary_id of “SNOMED”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a set of candidate mappings here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ykzbW-RMRJV4doIpZANibu45WveLFoFA/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=111904620053364392286&rtpof=true&sd=true

Note that these are just candidates that I made up. They're not approved by either the FHIR or OMOP communities. There's a joint working party between HL7 and OHDSI working through those proposed mappings checking them and filling in the blanks.